# 2-pin fan connector identification

Tags: identification, connector, fan

I can't find exactly this connector. It is from a small fan of a Lecroy Xs scope. The pitch is 0.05 inch. Does anyone happen to know who the manufacturer is, or what type this is?

[image: Front of connector]

[image: back of connector]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out. It is a Molex Pico-Spox 87439-0200.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a JST connector or a Molex PicoBlade. The particular JST series could be GH based on the measurement.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JST_connector
:)